# How to get the Gaussian matrix with variance σs in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm trying to design a line detector in opencv, and to do that, I need to get the Gaussian matrix with variance `σs`.

The final formula should be 
`H=Gσs∗(Gσd')T`, and `H` is the detector that I'm going to create, but I have no idea how am I supposed to create the matrix with the variance and furthermore calculate `H` finally.
**Update**

This is the full formula.where “T” is the transpose operation.`Gσd'` is the first-order derivative of a 1-D Gaussian function `Gσd` with varianceσd in this direction
[image]

[image]

****Update****

These are the two formulas that I want, I need `H` for further use so please tell me how to generate the matrix. thx!

Comment: I just answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64766664/4917686) for the first derivative, the same logic could be applied for the second.

Answer (score 1):

As a Gaussian filter is quite common, OpenCV has a built-in operation for it: [GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur).

When you use that function you can set the `ksize` argument to `0/0` to automatically compute the pixel size of the kernel from the given sigmas.

---

A Gaussian 2D filter kernel is separable. That means you can first apply a 1D filter along the x axis and then a 1D filter along the y axis. That is the reason for having two 1D filters in the equation above. It is much faster to do two 1D filter operations instead of one 2D.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't know how to get the result that I want. I'm not very familiar with `opencv` maybe more details? thanks again!

Comment: To be precise: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#smoothing

Comment: I've seen that tutorial, but how can I use that function? `GaussianBlur( src, dst, Size( 0, 0 ), σs, σd )`? but there is a `first-order`,I don't know whether this can get the result I want? can you please show me how to use the function?

Comment: @richard: Please be more specific. I do not understand your problem.

Comment: ok, I want to get `I0'` in the formula that I provide and I don't know how to use `GaussiaBlur` to get that, sorry for not being clear, I just don't know how to describe it clearly in English..

Comment: @richard: This is in detail described in the linked tutorial. Read it carefully, compile the example code and execute it.

Comment: @Danvil, I must be too stupid to understand that, I don't see what the `Gaussian blur` do with the first-order derivative, and I don't see how `Gaussianblur` give me the result that I want. I really need your explanation. thanks

Comment: I need to get the matrix, could you please show me how to generate it?