# How to apply a partial derivative Gaussian kernel to an image with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, gaussian, derivative

I'm trying reproduce results from a paper, in which they convolve the image with an horizontal partial derivative of a Gaussian kernel. I haven't found any way to achieve that with OpenCV. Is that possible ?

Do I have to get Gaussian filter and then compute the partial derivatives by hand ?

Comment: No, you can do that with OpenCV. First build your kernel (e.g. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaussiankernel)) and then [apply it](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't have built-in function to calculate Gaussian partial derivatives. But you may use [`cv::getGaussianKernel`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaussiankernel) and [`cv::filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) to do so.

For example:

```
  cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaussianKernel(3, 0.85, CV_32F);
  kernel = kernel.reshape(1, 1);
  cv::filter2D(img, img, CV_8U, kernel);
```

Please note that `cv::getGaussianKernel` returns column filter, so you need `reshape` to make it horizontal.

Comment: I would not have thought that was that easy.

Comment: @akarsakov these lines of code implement a convolution with a Gaussian kernel or with the derivative of it? It seems to be the former

Comment: This is just GaussianBlur it is not the derivative

Answer (score 5):

As @akarsakov said OpenCV does not provide a built-in function for this. However, we can still use OpenCV's `getGaussianKernel()` and then apply a factor to get the derivative.

Since a Gaussian 2D kernel is separable, that function will simply return you a 1D kernel and assume that you will apply a 1D filter along the x-axis and then a 1D filter along the y-axis, which is faster than applying the 2D kernel directly.

Since you want the horizontal Gaussian derivative, [ref](http://campar.in.tum.de/Chair/HaukeHeibelGaussianDerivatives):

[image]

You can simply multiply by `-x/sigma^2` each point of the kernel.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kernel_size = 13
sigma = 0.5
kernel = cv2.getGaussianKernel(kernel_size, sigma, cv2.CV_64F)
print(kernel)

gaussian_first_deriv_x = np.zeros_like(kernel)
assert(kernel_size % 2 == 1) # I assume you are using an odd kernel_size
half_kernel_size = int(kernel_size / 2)
for i in range(kernel_size):
    x = - half_kernel_size + i
    factor = - x/ (sigma**2)
    gaussian_first_deriv_x[i] = kernel[i] * factor

print(gaussian_first_deriv_x)

plt.plot(kernel[:], 'b')
plt.plot(gaussian_first_deriv_x[:], 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, you can do your convolution using this kernel.

Note: if you are using Python you can alternatively use the function `ndimage.gaussian_filter1d(data, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')` from `from scipy import ndimage`.

OpenCV by default uses the following: `sigma = 0.3 * (kernel_size / 2.0 - 1) + 0.8`.